# Pygame making a selection like in stategy games

Tags: pygame

So I made this in order to select an area like in strategy games, however
the screen keeps blinking, is there a way to solve this?

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLUE = (0,0,255)

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
window.fill(WHITE)
pygame.display.flip()

LEFT_CLIC = 1
mouse_tracking = False
draw_area = False
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            continuer = 0

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == LEFT_CLIC:
                x_start, y_start = event.pos
                x_end, y_end = event.pos
                mouse_tracking = True
                draw_area = True

        if event.type == MOUSEMOTION and mouse_tracking:
            x_end, y_end = event.pos

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if event.button == LEFT_CLIC:
                x_end, y_end = event.pos
                mouse_tracking = True
                draw_area = False

    if draw_area:
        width = x_end-x_start
        height = y_end-y_start
        pygame.draw.rect(window, BLUE, (x_start, y_start, width, height))
    pygame.display.flip()
    window.fill(WHITE)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

So it's pretty simple, record coordinates when there is a clic, then follow the mouse until the clic is done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be only one `pygame.display.flip()` call per frame, otherwise you get this flickering, so remove one of them. Also, fill the screen before you draw the rect.

```
window.fill(WHITE)

if draw_area:
    width = x_end-x_start
    height = y_end-y_start
    pygame.draw.rect(window, BLUE, (x_start, y_start, width, height))

pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: ah yes, If I fill it before I only have to do one flip, thanks :D